# beginner form with "update from" and "remove" buttons

Tags: php, mysql, post

I'm a beginner with PHP. I watched a tutorial to create a form which modifies my wamp-created mysql database table. Copied the video at first, but then made my own table from scratch and tried to upgrade it.

My add row works correctly, but the update and remove do not. I think the `WHERE` clause is not correct, referencing `reg_id`.

I created a unique primary key, which auto-increments and cannot be modified; this is what I want to reference when changes are made (since it cannot be changed).

```
if (isset($_POST['update'])){
$UpdateQuery = "UPDATE register SET First_Name='$_POST[first_name]', Last_Name='$_POST[last_name]', Breed='$_POST[breed]', Weight='$_POST[weight]', Age='$_POST[age]', Sex='$_POST[sex]' WHERE '$_POST[reg_id]'='$_POST[reg_id]'";
mysqli_query($con,$UpdateQuery);};

if (isset($_POST['delete'])){
$DeleteQuery = "DELETE FROM register WHERE reg_id='$_POST[reg_id]'";
mysqli_query($con,$DeleteQuery);};
```

Here is the rest of it where the form is located:

```
while($record=mysqli_fetch_array($myData)){
  echo "<form action=register.php method=post>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $record['reg_id'] . " </td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=first_name value=" . $record['First_Name'] . " </td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=last_name value=" . $record['Last_Name'] . " </td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=breed value=" . $record['Breed'] . " </td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input type=int name=weight value=" . $record['Weight'] . " </td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input type=int name=age value=" . $record['Age'] . " </td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=sex value=" . $record['Sex'] . " </td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=update value=update" . " </td>";
  echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=delete value=delete" . " </td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "</form>";
}
```

Please help me fix it.

[image]

Comment: now is a good time to get in the habit of quoting your input attribute values, ie. `... name='first_name' value ='" . $record['First_Name'] . "' ...`. unquoted values for your attributes is going to cause you headaches very soon. Also, you are not closing your `name=update`/`name=delete` inputs. They are missing the `/>`.

Comment: You should use prepared statements, this is open to SQL injections. You where clause is missing the column you want to check the `id` against the column should also be in backticks, not quotes.

Comment: Your  `reg_id` is not in an input, so there is no `$_POST['reg_id']` -> `echo "<td>" . $record['reg_id'] . " </td>";`

Comment: instead input type="submit" use `<a href="update.php?reg_id=".$record['reg_id'].">Edit</a>` the redirect to an edit form

Comment: Guys - Thanks for the responses. I will clean the code up, and yes, I have an error with the reg_id. Thats what I need help with. How should it be changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (isset($_POST['update'])){
$UpdateQuery = "UPDATE register SET First_Name='".$_POST['first_name']."',Last_Name='".$_POST['last_name']."', Breed='".$_POST['breed']."', Weight='".$_POST['weight']."', Age='".$_POST['age']."', Sex='".$_POST['sex']."' WHERE reg_id ='".$_POST['reg_id']."'";
mysqli_query($con,$UpdateQuery);
};

if (isset($_POST['delete'])){
$DeleteQuery = "DELETE FROM register WHERE reg_id='".$_POST['reg_id']."'";
mysqli_query($con,$DeleteQuery);
};
```

should be enclosed by **'** ,that is optional.add hidden will be more better

```
echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='reg_id' value='".$record['reg_id']."'></td>";
echo "<td><input type='submit' name='update' value='update'></td>";
echo "<td><input type='submit' name='delete' value='delete'></td>";
```

Comment: as mentioned to others, there is an issue with `$_POST['reg_id']`, as the OP has `echo "<td>" . $record['reg_id'] . " </td>";`.

Comment: that looks better, although an explanation about your change to `value='".$record['reg_id']."'` would be helpful.

Comment: thanks. this did the trick. looks like i just needed to have the form call & store reg_id into via name='reg_id'.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$_POST` without `'`.

Try this : `{$_POST['first_name']}` and replace all `$_POST` according to this.

So your update query will be like this :

```
"UPDATE register SET First_Name='{$_POST['first_name']}', Last_Name='{$_POST['last_name']}', Breed='{$_POST['breed']}', Weight='{$_POST['weight']}', Age='{$_POST['age']}', Sex='{$_POST['sex']}' WHERE reg_id='{$_POST['reg_id']}'";
```

There is no field with name `reg_id`, so your `$_POST['reg_id']` will not work.Also please change your where condition. You are matching same value in where condition.

And your delete query will be :

```
"DELETE FROM register WHERE reg_id='{$_POST['reg_id']}'";
```

Your query is open for sql injection. Refer this  :[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: inside double quotes `"$_POST[first_name]"`, keys don't need to be quoted.  But if they are quoted, then the brackets `{ }` are required.

Answer (score 0):

**display page**

```
while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($myData)) {
            echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$record['reg_id']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$record['First_Name']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$record['Last_Name']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$record['Breed']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$record['Weight']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$record['Age']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$record['Sex']."</td>";
            echo "<td><a href='edit.php?reg_id=".$record['reg_id']."'>EDIT</a></td>";
            echo "<td><a href='delete.php?reg_id=".$record['reg_id']."'>DELETE</a></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "</table>";
        }
```

**delete.php**

```
  <?php 
    if (isset($_POST['delete'])){
    $DeleteQuery = "DELETE FROM `register` WHERE `reg_id`={$_GET['reg_id']}'";
    mysqli_query($con,$DeleteQuery);
   header("Location: your display page");
};
    ?>
```

**Edit Form**

```
while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($myData)) {
    echo '<form action="edit.php" method="Post">
            <input type="text" name="First_Name" value="'.$record['reg_id'].'"/>
            <input type="text" name="First_Name" value="'.$record['First_Name'].'"/>
            <input type="text" name="Last_Name" value="'.$record['Last_Name'].'"/>
            <input type="text" name="Breed" value="'.$record['Breed'].'"/>
            <input type="text" name="Weight" value="'.$record['Weight'].'"/>
            <input type="text" name="Age" value="'.$record['Age'].'"/>
            <input type="text" name="Sex" value="'.$record['Sex'].'"/>
            <imput type="submit" value="save" name="submit" />
        </form>';
    }
```

**edit.php**

```
       if (isset($_POST['update'])){
        $UpdateQuery = "UPDATE `register` SET `First_Name`='{$_POST['first_name']}', `Last_Name`='{$_POST['last_name']}', `Breed`='{$_POST['breed']}', Weight='{$_POST['weight']}', `Age`={$_POST['age']}, Sex='{$_POST['sex']}' WHERE `reg_id`={$_GET['reg_id']}";
        mysqli_query($con,$UpdateQuery);
        header("Location: your display page");
};
```

Comment: Big problem in that `$_POST['reg_id']` does not exist, as there is not input element with the `reg_id`.

Comment: That is even worse. How will the OP get a `$_GET` from `<form action=register.php method=post>`? Also, why did  you do `$_GET` in the `UPDATE`, but still have `$_POST` in the `DELETE`?

Comment: instead of using input type="submit" use <a href="update.php?reg_id=".$record['reg_id'].">Edit</a> the redirect to an edit form, by the he could $_GET the reg_id @Sean

Comment: well, then that would be good to put in your answer, as that makes a major change to the OP's current structure, as that is their edit form. so now you are recommending that they have a link in their edit form to a new edit form, instead of just posting the data in their current edit form.

Comment: yeah, as much as possible i have to be inline with the question and do not revise his whole question. my bad

Comment: no, if you feel that there is a better way to do something, you can do that on SO. You just need to clearly explain it in your answer, not as a comment. There are many times that I have given answers that show the OP how to completely redo their code. You just need to give clear reasons why your way would better accomplish what they intend to do. Happy coding!

Comment: Matt - Thanks for the recommendation, however it doesn't fix my issue. The update and delete buttons don't work due to my incorrect usage of reg_id. How do I fix that?

Comment: i've revised the code for simplicity purposes, that's what i have in mind to avoid you from getting mixed up..